# jQuery - Loading Thumbnails

Tags: jquery

basically I have thumbnails at the bottom of the page and one large image. I want to be able to hover over the thumbnails and have the source of the thumbnail replace that of the big image so the thumbnail takes its place.

Please someone help!! I need to get this finished asap, is there any other info I should provide?!

This is the code I am using:

```
jQuery('.image-rollover').hover(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/);
    jQuery('.replace img').replace("src", src);
});
```

Comment: what is the problem in this  ? are you getting any error ?

Comment: I am not getting an error on document ready, but when I hover over the thumbnail for which I want to capture the source I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'attr'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('.image-rollover').hover(function() {
    jQuery('.replace img').attr("src", this.src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea of how you might want to set this up:

http://jsfiddle.net/GuSeg/

You want to swap the src of your mainImage with the src of the hovered image which is done by:

```
$('.thumbnailToHoverOn').hover(function(){
    $("#mainImg").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});​
```

Comment: A link to jsfiddle, while nice to include, should not be the sum-total of an answer.  Please explain what you've done, provide sample code, etc.

Comment: with this example its throwing this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL